# contentInset for QLPreviewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I am refactoring my app for iOS 7, i have a view controller with UIToolBar in the top and below that QLPreviewController.
I set the UIToolBar translucent to YES and the origin y of the QLPreviewController is the same as the toolbar`s y origin (so i will be able to see the QLPreviewController behind the tool bar).

Right now the content of the QLPreviewController is cut and i would like to set the content inset to begin at 44.0 (toolbar's height) and not 0.0.

screenshot:
[image]

Can i access the QLPreviewController`s ScrollView?
How do i do it?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try to add this line to your viewController:


`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;`


You can read up on this change to ScrollView content insets [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html)

Comment: After struggling with QLPreviewController's scroll view, I found out that if I use UIWebView to display the PDF, it uses the same rendering, AND gives access to webview.scrollView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `NO`:

```
QLPreviewController *previewViewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewViewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
//code for push/present previewViewController
```

or set `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone`:

```
QLPreviewController *previewViewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
//code for push/present previewViewController
```